# System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException: Unknown error (0x80005000)

Tags: c#, iis

This is the detailed error info.

> Failures: 
>   System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation. ---> System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException: Unknown error (0x80005000)
>      at System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryEntry.Bind(Boolean throwIfFail)
>      at System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryEntry.Bind()
>      at System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryEntry.get_NativeObject()

Code that causes the above exception:

```
 DirectoryEntry de1 = new DirectoryEntry("RNA:");
 IRnaNamespace rnaNamespace = (IRnaNamespace)de1.NativeObject;
```

After the **del** object is created, I try to watch the values for variant **del**, and this is the result:
[link text](http://picasaweb.google.com/lh/photo/WFhTvRWS2w3TL-gad1OvuQ?feat=directlink)
[alt text http://lh4.ggpht.com/_ZgKaPEWP-AM/SwEIByd3XiI/AAAAAAAAAtE/ljuXhGUWd4g/s912/Untitled.png](http://lh4.ggpht.com/_ZgKaPEWP-AM/SwEIByd3XiI/AAAAAAAAAtE/ljuXhGUWd4g/s912/Untitled.png)

The OS is Windows2008 R2 64bits. And it can run successfully on Windows2008Sp2 32bit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is caused by the following statement:

```
DirectoryEntry de1 = new DirectoryEntry("RNA:");
```

Because it will call another project **AAA** which is built in 32 bits system to create the directory. After rebuilt **AAA** in 64 bits, everything is OK.